# How to write to file, but not rewrite it in android?

Tags: android, file

I have android app, and there is some variables. I want to write to file every message after click on the button. How can I do it? After each click on button I call this method.

But this code rewrites me file always... I tried google, but everywhere is only rewriting.

```
    try {
        String fpath = "/sdcard/"+"NAME"+".txt";
        File file = new File(fpath);
        // If file does not exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(msg);
        bw.close();
        //Log.d("Suceess", "Sucess");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

According to the [FileWriter docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) passing `true` as the second parameter on the constructor makes it append to a file, not over-write.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a `RandomAccessFile` to append text:

```
        try {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(yourTxt.getAbsolutePath(), "rw");
        if (txt.length() > 0) {
            raf.seek(txt.length());
            raf.write("\n".getBytes());
            raf.write(yourString.getBytes());
            raf.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and by the way, using search definitely [helps](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java%20append%20to%20file)